# How to detect event object created in .NET from Win32

Tags: .net, winapi, events

I am creating a named event object in .NET using interop calls like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(IntPtr lpEventAttributes, bool bManualReset,
    bool bInitialState, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpName);

const string EVENT_NAME = "Global\\unique_id_string";
const uint SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000;
const uint EVENT_MODIFY_STATE = 0x0002;
hEvent = CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, true, false, EVENT_NAME);
```

And then I try to open this event from a Win32 program like this

```
WCHAR evntName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
wcscpy(evntName, L"Global\\unique_id_string");
HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, evntName);
```

But the handle returned is always 0.

When I try the same from another .NET application like this,

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr OpenEvent(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritable,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpName);

const string EVENT_NAME = "Global\\unique_id_string";
const uint SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000;
const uint EVENT_MODIFY_STATE = 0x0002;

IntPtr hEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE, false, EVENT_NAME);
```

it works perfectly and returns the correct handle to the event.

Why is it not working with the native C++ application? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: In your native application, what does `GetLastError()` return? (0, or rather NULL, indicates failure, but you need to find out what failure.)

Comment: Also, are you leaving the event creating application running? When there are no references to a kernel object it will be destroyed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. GetLastError() returns 2 which is the system error code for ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. That has me completely perplexed. Yes, the event creating application is running in the background. It runs minimized in the system tray.

Comment: File Not Found, for a named object, means "no such object with that name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32 API calls come in two versions -- ANSI and Unicode. According to the docs for [`DllImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx), you must specify this as a `CharSet` attribute, otherwise it defaults to the ANSI version. Even though you are marshaling the string as `LPWStr`, you are actually invoking the ANSI version and it most likely sees only the first character of the name `G`. But your Win32 application is using the full Unicode name (as you intended) but fails to find such a named event.

Try explicitly importing the Unicode version of the function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

If you specify the `CharSet`, you also don't need to specify the marshaling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

While ANSI/Unicode might be the problem, the ANSI APIs work by mapping strings to Unicode and then calling the Unicode code path. So that shouldn't be a problem.

With an error of File Not Found there is a name mismatch. Try changing the native app to use [`CreateEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396%28VS.85%29.aspx) as well (if the name exists you get a handle, and `GetLastError()` returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS—thus the pattern of `CreateEvent` and always checking last error to avoid timing dependencies or race conditions around object creation.

If you don't get a name collision, use [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896655) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653) (both SysInternals) to look at the event object to see what its name really is.

---

### **UPDATE**

#### What happened (TL:DR: version):

Telling P/Invoke that it is an ANSI API (the default, if you don't specif Unicode) and saying the string is Unicode gives wrong results. Fixing either of these would resolve the problem.

#### Fuller version:

The original P/Inovoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(IntPtr lpEventAttributes, bool bManualReset,
        bool bInitialState, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpName);
```

has the default (ANSI) API method (because `DllImport`'s `CharSet` property defaults to `CharSet.Ansi`) ***but*** the string has `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`: pass a *wide* (i.e. Unicode) string.

If you look at the name of the object when this is running you see:

```
\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\G
```

where the API has just seen the `G` from the name, and add the per-session name prefix.

Modifying the declaration to:
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(IntPtr lpEventAttributes, bool bManualReset,
            bool bInitialState, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpName);

passing an ANSI string to an ANSI API, or

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(IntPtr lpEventAttributes, bool bManualReset,
        bool bInitialState, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpName);
```

passing a Unicode string to a Unicode API both work, with an object name created:

```
\BaseNamedObjects\unique_id_string
```

(`Global` is an alias in the Kernel object tree for `BaseNamedObjects`.)

#### Summary:

P/Invoke declarations need to be 100% correct... even one character is significant.

Comment: Even though they may internally map to Unicode, the input string is treated as an ANSI string and it would end up seeing only the first character of the Unicode string.

Comment: Somehow it only works when Unicode is explicitly specified. This solution combined with the Charset method does the trick for me very well.

Comment: @casablanca that wasn't my understanding: a correct transcoding is performed from the correct ANSI code page to Unicode. Thus ANSI text output functions write more than one character. I suspect more a case of P/Invoke and marshalling mixing things up.

Comment: Since Unicode strings are encoded as UTF-16, `L"hello"` would look like `h\0e\0l\0l\0o\0\0\0` in memory. An ANSI `"hello"` would simply be `hello\0`. ANSI functions will stop at the first NULL character, hence the Unicode string will look like `"h"`. You can test this yourself by passing a Unicode string to an ANSI function, for eg. `MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)L"hello", NULL, 0)` will just display `h`.

Comment: @casablanca: I'm updating with root cause here (inconsistent P/invoke). Calling the ANSI version of `CreateEvent` also works.